# Masterpages jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Hi
 i am using master pages webmethod for calling auto complete my code js is

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#ctl00_TextBox1').keyup(function(e) {
        //$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTest').keyup(function(e) {
        alert("hi");
        var msgbox = $("#status");
        var tx_val = document.getElementById("ctl00_TextBox1").value;
        alert(tx_val);
        if (e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 37) {
            // debugger;
            // alert("hi");
            //debugger;

            $.ajax({

                // alert("ajax");
                type: "POST",
                //Page Name (in which the method should be called) and method name
                url: "Default.aspx/CheckDateTime",
                // If you want to pass parameter or data to server side function you can try line

                data: "{'args':'" + tx_val + "'}",
                //else If you don't want to pass any value to server side function leave the data to blank line below
                // data: "{}",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                success: function(msg) {
                    //Got the response from server and render to the client
                    msgbox.html(msg.d);
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

My problem is that this code runs in normal pages like aspx pages when I am using master page pages that the code is not working properly
means code is running upto `alert(tx)val);` after ajax extension is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs will change depending on which page (or rather, how nested) they are in, first I'd replace this:

```
var tx_val = document.getElementById("ctl00_TextBox1").value;
```

With this:

```
var tx_val = $(this).val();
```

---

The your selector, if it's in the page, do this:

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').keyup(function(e) {
```

If it's outside the page, give it a class like this:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="TextBox1" CssClass="dateTime" runat="server" />
```

And use that class for your selector:

```
$('.dateTime').keyup(function(e) {
```

....this also allows you to move your script to be completely external, not relying on anything generated by the page.

---

Another potential issue is `"Default.aspx/CheckDateTime"` not being relative to the current path, make sure where you are that this is appropriate, you may want an absolute path instead, like `"/Default.aspx/CheckDateTime"`...I can't tell by your posted code if this is on every page, or on a single page you always want to go to.

Comment: but i did not get the solution

Comment: @sampath - you're not describing what *doesn't* work very well...what is the issue here, which part is failing?

Answer (score 0):

its because the client id of the textbox is not ctl00_TextBox1 anymore. when using a master page, the contentplaceholder id gets appended to the client id too. so you better use the approach suggested by Nick Craver or grab the new clientid by setting a breakpoint and reading the ClientID property

Comment: i capture that ids also i applied that id's when using that time the webmethod is not calling

Answer (score 0):

You can also find that element by its class, rather than id.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="input" />
```

then update your js to be:

```
var tx_val = $(".input").value;
```

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `.value` property...and `.val()` would get the *first* element that selector matches, you're much better off with `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your selector, something like below code should work fine:

var tx_val = $('input[id$=TextBox1]').val();